# Poco SocketAddress does not prefer IPv4 Address with Preprocessor Macro defined

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Hello I have a problem with the `SocketAddress class` of Poco.
I passed in a Hostname and the resolved Addresses contains both an `IPv4` and an `IPv6` Address.
Inside the `init` Method of the `SocketAddress` is this piece of code:

```
if (addresses.size() > 0)
{
#if defined(POCO_HAVE_IPv6) && defined(POCO_SOCKETADDRESS_PREFER_IPv4)
    // if we get both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, prefer IPv4
    std::stable_sort(addresses.begin(), addresses.end(), AFLT());
#endif
    init(addresses[0], portNumber);
}
```

I added the Preprocessor Macro `POCO_SOCKETADDRESS_PREFER_IPv4` but it does not activate that part of the Code. The `POCO_HAVE_IPv6` Macro seems to be active by default. 
Do I have to add the `POCO_SOCKETADDRESS_PREFER_IPv4` when i build the Poco Lib?

Comment: When and where do you set the macro? When you're building the POCO library? Otherwise it won't work (unless the code you show is in a header file) since the library will already be built and macros you define won't affect an already built binary library.

Comment: You need to re-build the entire poco library to with the `POCO_SOCKETADDRESS_PREFER_IPv4`  setting , or you have to do the host name resolving yourself, pick out the IPv4 address and pass that IP address to `SocketAddress::init()`

Comment: Instead of rebuilding the whole library you can use `SocketAddress(Family family, const std::string& hostAddress, Poco::UInt16 portNumber);` overload and pass IPv4 as first argument.

Comment: Ok it seems like that i have to rebuild the libs because the `init` Function is called by the ICMPClient so i could not specify the address Family directly. I build the Lib on Windows using the `buildwin` script. How can i pass `Macros` to the build using that script?

Comment: I think you cannot pass define as parameter to `buildwin`. Take a look at `CMakeLists.txt` files in *Net*,*Foundtation*... folders in sources. Defines are passed by `add_definitions(-Dxxx)` so you may try modyfing CMakeLists.txt in Net directory adding `add_definitions(-DPOCO_SOCKETADDRESS_PREFER_IPv4)`.